# Academic / formal equivalent of : there are two sides to every story

Tags: phrase-requests, latin

"Every coin has two sides" or "there are two sides to every story" is often over-used and may even come off as cliche-sounding. I will of course use them still if that's what I really want to say.

However, in the spirit of curiosity, I want to find an existing academic-sounding equivalent of this concept.

To be more specific, what I don't like about it is how wordy it is. I want to reduce the core message to just 2-4 words.

My first thought was to use Latin to convey the core message, but perhaps that's not within the English SE periphery. Just for illustration, here is a somewhat common usage of Latin in English-language publications: chaos begets chaos

> abyssus abyssum invocat

How can I shorten or otherwise make "there are two sides to every story" more academic sounding?

Comment: Dual-sided story or event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Latin expression:

> **Audiatur et altera pars**

(literally, let the other side also be heard) is a relatively common exhortation, in English contexts, to keep in mind that there are two sides to every story.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **flip side** is what you're looking for

> The opposite side

*“The flip side of retrospectively savaging the loser is beatifying ... the winner” (Charles Krauthammer).*

[American Heritage Dictionary]